# Повторные заимствования

Tags: лексика

По каким причинам слова могут повторно заимствоваться? Как определить, что слово заимствовано повторно? Приведите, пожалуйста, примеры таких случаев.

Comment: Знать бы, что вы имеете в виду.

Comment: @behemothus см. мой ответ ниже

Answer (score 2):

Существует термин **"обратное (возвратное) заимствование".**

**Пример со словом "быстро"**, которое вошло во французскую речь в 1812 году, но при этом значение его не соответствовало оригиналу. "Быстро!" — это слово очень часто звучало в речи русских солдат, и так французы назвали небольшую закусочную.

А во второй половине 20 века русизм *bistro* вернулся на родину и тоже стал обозначать закусочную с быстрым обслуживанием.

Другой пример: будка — дощатое, отдельно стоящее строение для часового или сторожа. Слово известно и в других славянских языках, причем заимствовано оно из средневекового немецкого: хижина, каморка (от глагола *bauen* — строить). В скандинавских странах слово имело значение палатка, магазин, торговая лавка. Но вот современное сущ. в немецком языке *Baude* (горная турбаза) — это обратное заимствование из славянских языков.

Comment: *обратное (возвратное) заимствование* - у автора "повторное".

Comment: Что же касается ваших примеров, то такие вещи в языке не редкость, слово возвращается в язык ***в другом значении*** (и поэтому термин "обратное" не совсем точен). И это не говоря уж о том, что этимология французского "бистро" от русского "быстро" отрицается абсолютным большинством французских специалистов. Об этом даже вики упоминает. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE

Comment: Термин "обратное"  и пример с  "бистро" взяты из следующего источника: http://alarm.iponi.net/romany/bool-4606.htm  Также: http://www.fil.unn.ru/ffil/kafedry-fakulteta-2/ksr/marinova-elena-vyacheslavovna/

Comment: Миф о русских корнях "бистро" "знают" все наши соотечественники: Харч! Быстро! - так победители подгоняли медлительных французских официантов. http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/19944-otkuda-pojavilos-slovo-bistro.htmlно Но вот французские этимологи категорически против этой "фантазии".

Answer (score 1):

### О типах заимствования

Следует различать:

1. "Материальное заимствование", при котором воспроизводится как форма, так и значение заимствуемого слова (ср. многочисленные англицизмы, которые появились в русском языке за последние полтора десятилетия для обозначения отсутствовавших ранее реалий, типа *маркетинг* или *мерчендайзинг*; некоторые из них вполне освоены языком, как, например, слово *грант*);
2. Заимствование внешней оболочки слова с изменением его значения в направлении  "приспособления" к семантической системе заимствующего языка (ср. *кураж, авантюра, гонор, гешефт*);
3. Семантическое калькирование, т. е. заимствование производного значения, отражающего способ построения концепта; при этом, наоборот, заимствующий язык оказывается под влиянием семантической системы языка-источника (ср. *друг* (= 'сожитель'), *успешный* <человек>); в случае, когда "мишенью" семантического калькирования является заимствованное слово (ср. *проблема, шок*), имеет место, так сказать, "**повторное заимствование**".

*По материалам книги Анны. А. Зализняк, И. Б. Левонтиной, А. Д. Шмелева "Константы и переменные русской языковой картины мира".*

Comment: Я убрал, но там кавычки стоят, это не термин, эпитет. Ссылочка есть на источник? Вообще не понимаю смысла этой сентенции... Первые два понимаю - третий нет. Надо побробно разбираться, что имеется в виду.

Comment: @behemothus у меня книга, а [пиратствовать](http://www.twirpx.com/file/2109544/) [(2)](https://goo.gl/1GmRcd) — плохо. Там дальше довольно подробно и со ссылками на авторитетных исследователей все разъясняется. Если никому ничего в голову больше не придет, перепечатаю.

Comment: Да причем тут пиратствовать?! Ладно, попрошу у Шмелева, если встречусь. ))))

Comment: @behemothus на (2) нажмите, там, в принципе, все, о чем я говорил. Зачем Алексея Дмитриевича понапрасну беспокоить))

Comment: Ничего, я его почти полвека знаю. Не виделись, конечно, сто лет, я на встречи одноклассников не хожу...

Comment: @behemothus а, ну тогда если потолкуете, напишите о результате. Может, чего нового выясните.